# TypeError: in method 'IndexIDMap_add_with_ids', argument 4 of type 'faiss::IndexIDMapTemplate< faiss::Index >::idx_t const *'

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, sentence

**I'm trying to do semantic search with Pre trained bert models and transformers. I'm using Facebook AI library Faiss.**

The code is :

```
encoded_data = model.encode(df.Plot.tolist())
encoded_data = np.asarray(encoded_data.astype('float32'))
index = faiss.IndexIDMap(faiss.IndexFlatIP(768))
index.add_with_ids(encoded_data, np.array(range(0, len(encoded_data))))
faiss.write_index(index, 'movie_plot.index')
```

The error it's returning is :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c09b9ccadf2a> in <module>
----> 1 index.add_with_ids(encoded_data, np.array(range(0, len(encoded_data))))
      2 faiss.write_index(index, 'movie_plot.index')

~\t5\lib\site-packages\faiss\__init__.py in replacement_add_with_ids(self, x, ids)
    233 
    234         assert ids.shape == (n, ), 'not same nb of vectors as ids'
--> 235         self.add_with_ids_c(n, swig_ptr(x), swig_ptr(ids))
    236 
    237     def replacement_assign(self, x, k, labels=None):

~\t5\lib\site-packages\faiss\swigfaiss.py in add_with_ids(self, n, x, xids)
   4950 
   4951     def add_with_ids(self, n, x, xids):
-> 4952         return _swigfaiss.IndexIDMap_add_with_ids(self, n, x, xids)
   4953 
   4954     def add(self, n, x):

TypeError: in method 'IndexIDMap_add_with_ids', argument 4 of type 'faiss::IndexIDMapTemplate< faiss::Index >::idx_t const *'
```

**When i ran the same program in google colab, no error was returned. I'm running this program now in windows 10 local pc**

**I got the answer, we have to convert the np.array(range(0, len(encoded_data))) into int64**

```
encoded_data = model.encode(df.Plot.tolist())
encoded_data = np.asarray(encoded_data.astype('float32'))
index = faiss.IndexIDMap(faiss.IndexFlatIP(768))
ids = np.array(range(0, len(df)))
ids = np.asarray(ids.astype('int64'))
index.add_with_ids(encoded_data, ids)
faiss.write_index(index, 'movie_plot.index')
```

Comment: I suggest adding your solution as an answer. The original poster is allowed and encouraged to answer their own question when they find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you migth convert `encoded_data.astype('float32')` after having done `np.asarray(encoded_data)` such as:

```py
np.asarray(encoded_data).astype('float32')
```

Comment: encoded_data is already converted into float32. The actual answer is, we have to convert np.array(range(0, len(df))) into int64 type

Answer (score 0):

Faiss `add_with_ids()` only accepts ids of np.int64 dtype.
I didn't find Python documentation of this data type requirement, but this link https://faiss.ai/cpp_api/struct/structfaiss_1_1Index.html (although it's in c++) shows its id data type.